# Función con dos parametros de entrada

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, plsql

Amigos estoy haciendo una función con dos parámetros`(NU_DOCU,TIPO_DOCU)` de entrada que debe validar la longitud de 8 y 11 según el tipo de documento.

Los tipos de documentos son, `DNI- 8 Dígitos` y `RUC - 11 Dígitos`

`SELECT VALIDARDNI('12345678','A') FROM DUAL` debe devolver `-1`

La función que estaba desarrollando era ésta:

```
FUNCTION VALIDARDNI(NU_DOCUMENTO VARCHAR2,TI_DOCUMENTO VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    DNI VARCHAR2(100);    
    TIPO_DOCU VARCHAR2(3);
    V_ERROR NUMBER;             
    BEGIN
    ----Validar documento puede ser nulo
    IF LENGTH(LTRIM(TRIM(NU_DOCUMENTO))) = '' or NU_DOCUMENTO IS NULL THEN
       V_ERROR := -1;
    ELSE            
     ----Validar tamaño del Documento
     IF LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(NU_DOCUMENTO)))>=8 AND LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(NU_DOCUMENTO)))<='11' THEN
         V_ERROR := 1;
     ELSE
     V_ERROR := -1;
       END IF;
    END IF;
     TIPO_DOCU:=TI_DOCUMENTO;
     IF LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(TIPO_DOCU)))= '' OR TIPO_DOCU IS NULL THEN
     V_ERROR:=-1;
     ELSE
        IF (LTRIM(RTRIM(NU_DOCUMENTO))) = '8' AND LTRIM(RTRIM(TIPO_DOCU))='DNI' THEN
              V_ERROR:=1;
        END IF;  
        IF (LTRIM(RTRIM(NU_DOCUMENTO))) = '11' AND LTRIM(RTRIM(TIPO_DOCU))='RUC' THEN
            V_ERROR:=1;
        END IF;        
     END IF;     
     RETURN V_ERROR;      
END;
```

Comment: Cuales son los tipos de documentos que existe? hablas de tipos de documentos pero no mencionas ninguno para incluirlos y que estos sean validados en la funcion! si los tipos de documentos son (DNI y RUC) no tendrias que pasar 2 parametros solo 1 parametro y si es 8 seria DNI, y si es 11 seria RUC es eso lo que quieres?

Comment: si eso es lo que quiero si el documento tiene longitud 8 debe ser DNI y si tiene longitud 11 debe ser RUC

Answer (score 0):

Así debería ser el procedimiento, aunque no le cambie mucho de lo que habías realizado:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION VALIDARDNI(NU_DOCUMENTO VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    DNI VARCHAR2(100);
    V_ERROR NUMBER;             
    BEGIN
    ----Validar documento puede ser nulo
    IF ((LENGTH(LTRIM(TRIM(NU_DOCUMENTO))) = '') or (NU_DOCUMENTO IS NULL)) THEN
       V_ERROR := -1;
    ELSE            
     ----Validar tamaño del Documento
     IF ((LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(NU_DOCUMENTO)))>=8) AND (LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(NU_DOCUMENTO)))<='11')) THEN
         V_ERROR := 1;
     ELSE
     V_ERROR := -1;
     END IF;
    END IF;

     RETURN V_ERROR;      
END;
```